# call linux command via fork() and execlp()

Tags: c, linux

I am learning ipc and want to make mini-shell for pipe command execution 
I was trying to run linux command by use of this c code now i able to run commands like ls,date,pwd but not like ls -ltr or cd .. ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include "apue.h"

int main(void){

char buf[MAXLINE];
pid_t pid;
int status;
printf("%% ");

while(fgets(buf,MAXLINE,stdin) != NULL){

if(buf[strlen(buf)-1] == '\n')
 buf[strlen(buf)-1] = 0 ;

if((pid = fork()) < 0 ){
   printf("fork error");
}else if(pid == 0){
  execlp(buf , buf, (char * ) 0);
  printf("coulden't exceute : %s",buf);
  exit(127);

  }   
   if((pid = waitpid(pid,&status,0)) < 0)
   printf("waitpid error"); 
   printf("%% ");

  }
    exit(0);
  }
```

Comment: Splitting command lines into executable and arguments is a shell feature and therefore your job as the shell programmer. See `man execvp` for how to pass an executable an array of arguments. `cd` is a separate story that you have to implement yourself through `chdir`